# C fgetc() on socket/file stream while checking for EOF goes into infinite loop

Tags: c, loops, eof, infinite, fgetc

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int conn_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct addrinfo hints;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    struct addrinfo *addr = (struct addrinfo *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

    getaddrinfo("google.com", "80", &hints, &addr);

    connect(conn_s, addr->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    char *http_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n";

    send(conn_s, http_request, strlen(http_request), 0);
    FILE *sockfile = (FILE *) fdopen(conn_s, "r");
    FILE *fp = fopen("/Users/leekaiwei/Desktop/results.html", "w+");
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(sockfile)) != EOF) {
        fprintf(fp, "%c", ch);
    }

    close(conn_s);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(sockfile);
    free(addr);
    return 0;
}
```

The while loop never ends. Why is this? I have done this with a local file and it works fine. It also works fine with a for loop, it's just that the fgetc() never returns EOF.

Comment: There's a typo in http_request - it should end with "\r\n\r\n".  Is it possible that the http server doesn't send any response because your request is incomplete?  That'd make your fgetc call block.

Comment: Yeah, try to check e.g. tcpdump or wireshark if you receive answer from server...

Comment: Once you start getting data returned, I think you'll need to add your own code to spot the end of a http response rather than assuming fgetc will return EOF.  If the server keeps your connection alive, there is no way for lower level code to infer EOF.

Comment: "The while loop never ends." By this, I presume you mean, fgetc "hangs" waiting for input or EOF, and not that while loop keeps rolling and printing chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTP/1.1` defaults to `connection: keepalive`, so like simonc said, the server is actually waiting for you to make the next request, and will wait until a server-dependent timeout.
Use `HTTP/1.0` to get `EOF`.

FWIW: it took 245 seconds to complete.

Comment: Alternatively, include `Connection: close` as part of the HTTP/1.1 headers.  And, if using this code for generic HTTP connections, be sure to include the `Host:` header as well, since many websites use "named virtual hosting" and require that header.